# Unable to clone app engine project in pycharm

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

I am trying to clone an App Engine project written in python, into Pycharm.

My version of git is 1.9
I have the latest version of PyCharm.

I have run gcloud auth login so that I can authenticate using my google account. When I try to clone the repository at https://source.developers.google.com/p/APP-ENGINE-PROJECT

I get a dialog box similar to the one below, request me to enter a username and password.

[image]

I enter my gmail account but I can't login. It tells me it can't connect to the repository.

Please help.

Comment: How are you cloning it?

Comment: Using pycharm directly as opposed to git from the terminal.

Comment: You have to clone it with gcloud, not git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Create a directory where you want your local Git repository to be located and navigate to it.

   $mkdir directory

   $cd directory
2. Run the gcloud auth login command. This command gets the credentials required to access your Cloud Repository from the Google Cloud Platform.

   $ gcloud auth login
3. Run the gcloud init command. This command creates the local Git repository and adds your Cloud Repository as the Git origin remote.

   $ gcloud init project_id

The gcloud init command creates a directory named project_id/default in the current directory. The default directory contains your local Git repository.

4. Run PyCharm and do one of the following:

   - On the Welcome screen, click Open
   - On the main menu, choose File | Open.
5. In the Select Path dialog box, select the directory named project_id/default

Pycharm will connect to the repository automatically.